# How to replicate GridSearchCV result?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, auc, gridsearchcv

Using `GridSearchCV`, I try to maximize `AUC` for a `LogisticRegression Classifier`

```
clf_log = LogisticRegression(C=1, random_state=0).fit(X_train, y_train)

from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV

grid_params = {'penalty': ['l1','l2'], 'C': [0.001,0.01,0.1,1,10,100], 'max_iter' : [100]} 
gs = GridSearchCV(clf_log, grid_params, scoring='roc_auc', cv=5)
gs.fit(X_train, y_train)`
```

I got `gs.best_score_` of `0.7630647186779661` with `gs.best_estimator_` and `gs.best_params_`, respectively as follow:

```
<< LogisticRegression(C=10, class_weight=None, dual=False, fit_intercept=True,
                   intercept_scaling=1, l1_ratio=None, max_iter=100,
                   multi_class='auto', n_jobs=None, penalty='l2',
                   random_state=0, solver='lbfgs', tol=0.0001, verbose=0,
                   warm_start=False) >>

{'C': 10, 'max_iter': 100, 'penalty': 'l2'}
```

However, when I reintroduced these params into my original `clf_log`, I only got `AUC` of  `0.5359918677005525`. What am I missing (I think: CV part)? How can I get and replicate the same results? Thanks!

Comment: Where do you get the 0.53 AUC?  Is that when you execute against your X_test?  Because as far as I understand the GridSearchCV is applying k-fold validation and only looks at your training data.  So maybe you are overfitting or your test dataset is considerably different from your training dataset?

Comment: 0.53 using the same training data.

Comment: but if you want to evaluate your classifier, typically you have to evaluate against test data that has never been passed.  And are you fitting your GridSearchCV even?  I see you apply a fit against your LogisticRegression, but you have to call gs.fit() as well, as that will perform all cross fold validations

Comment: Yes gs.fit(X_train, y_train) was ran.

Comment: If my answer below has helped you, consider upvoting and accepting it. It'll help me, you and others trying to get an answer to a similar question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grid Search CV uses K fold cross validation, i.e. when you use the `fit` method, it divides the data into test and train sets (cv=5 means test set is 1/5 of the dataset) and this is done `cv` times (5 in this case). So you shouldn't be using `X_train` and `y_train`, instead use `X` and `y` (assuming you don't want a third validation set) as the splitting gets done internally.

```
gs.fit(X, y)
```

After this let's say your best parameters are `{'C': 10, 'max_iter': 100, 'penalty': 'l2'}`. Now say you want to apply this. If want to replicate the output of your GridSearchCV, then you need to use k fold cross validation again (If you use `train_test_split` instead, your results will slightly vary).

```
from sklearn.model_selection import cross_val_score
np.average(cross_val_score(LogisticRegression(C=10, max_iter=100, penalty='l2'), X, y, scoring='roc_auc', cv=10))
```

With this you should be getting the same AUC. You can refer this [video](https://youtu.be/HdlDYng8g9s)

Comment: Thanks - To clarify, does this mean even under `CV K-fold` (5), the model is just tested 5 times separately and not improving the single model by training it 5 times cumulatively?

Comment: The model is trained 5 times, each time with a different train and test split, and the final score is the average of all 5 scores. This is done so that the final scores (accuracy etc.) aren't out lied by a specific test and train split. **No the single model isn't improved cumulatively**, but it's still recommended. I suggest watching a tutorial on k fold cross validation on YouTube for more clarification.